# Only one part of code works at a time - issue with onTouchListener?

Tags: android

My `.java` file is truly puzzling: when a user touches the screen, I would like two things to happen.

- First, the coordinates of the touch event must appear
- Second, the coordinates of a textView must appear

In my code, only one of these will occur. Below is my `.java` file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //**Part 1 begins here
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                    return true;
            }
            });
    //**Part 1 ends here

    //**Part 2 begins here      
        final TextView touchView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        final TextView viewLocat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
                    touchView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
                    viewLocat.setText(String.valueOf(viewLocation[0]) + "x" + String.valueOf(viewLocation[1]));
                return true;
            }
            });
    }
    //**Part 2 ends here

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
        }

    }
```

If I run the code like this, only Part 2 occurs (the `TextView` coordinates are shown, but the touchpoint coordinates are not shown). If I silence Part 2 using //, Part 1 occurs perfectly. I am completely perplexed as to why this happens, does anyone happen to know how I can fix it?

Comment: it is a setter, **set**OnTouchLister,

Comment: Kindly avoid `Copy+Paste`, you have used `touchLayout.setOnTou....` twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the OnTouchListener by calling `touchLayout.setOnTouchListener` twice.  Perhaps move the code from your first listener into the second one?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);
    final TextView touchView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    final TextView viewLocat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));

            int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
            touchView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
            viewLocat.setText(String.valueOf(viewLocation[0]) + "x" +     String.valueOf(viewLocation[1]));
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```